# Search bar is not working in swift 3. Cannot convert value of type (_) -> Bool to expected argument type NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, searchbar

It is continously showing error: Cannot convert value of type (_) -> Bool to expected argument type NSPredicate
On line :

```
filtered = OrdersArray.filter(using: { (text) -> Bool in
            let tmp: NSString = text
            let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filtered = OrdersArray.filter(using: { (text) -> Bool in
            let tmp: NSString = text
            let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
            return range.location != NSNotFound
        })

        if(filtered.count == 0){
            searchActive = false;
        } else {
            searchActive = true;
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Both `UISearchBarDelegate`, `UISearchDisplayDelegate` delegates are marked
`searchBarTextDidBeginEditing`, `searchBarTextDidEndEditing`, `searchBarCancelButtonClicked`, `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`
functions are written
Kindly tell me what else to do to search data in `NSMutableArray`.

This is my array.

```
{
orders =     (
            {
        "created_at" = "2017-05-01 04:49:17";
        id = 591;
        "order_status" = CONFIRMED;
        "pickup_code" = 4356219;
        store =             {
            address1 = "**********";
            city = "**********";
            description = "*************";
            logo = "fghdshdx.png";
            name = "*******";
            "postal_code" = 110006;
            storeTotal = "20.00";
            "store_id" = 4;
            "tin_number" = M1O2R3E4MORE;
        };
        total = "20.00";
        "updated_at" = "2017-05-01 04:49:20";
        "user_address_id" = "<null>";
        "user_id" = 5372;
        "user_name" = "Amit Sinha";
    }
);
status = 1;
```

}

Comment: What is the type of `filtered` array also `OrdersArray` is contains String as object?

Comment: @NiravD var OrdersArray = NSMutableArray(), var filtered:[String] = []

Comment: @RajatAttri like this you have to do var OrdersArray = [String]() and var filtered:[String] = [] and in view did load you can assign OrdersArray = ["San Francisco","New York","San Jose","Chicago","Los Angeles","Austin","Seattle"]

Comment: @RajatAttri Sweeper is posted solution.

Comment: @RajatAttri try this : let namePredicate =
                            NSPredicate(format: "yourkey %@","searched text");// replace your key with yourkey
                       let filtered = (self.arrQuestions as NSArray).filtered(using: namePredicate)

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use `NSArray`!

I guess your `OrdersArray` is an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`. You should just convert that to a swift array first:

```
let swiftArray = Array(OrdersArray).map {  $0 as! NSString }
```

Then filter the swift array:

```
filtered = swiftArray.filter(using: { (text) -> Bool in
    let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
    return range.location != NSNotFound
})
```

Comment: Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x1a7a25c50) to 'NSString' (0x1a7a35ae8).
2017-05-01 10:31:03.423309+0530 UniShop Merchant[3029:1014358] Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x1a7a25c50) to 'NSString' (0x1a7a35ae8).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this! reference from [This](http://shrikar.com/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate/)

```
  import UIKit

class SearchViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var SearchTableView: UITableView!

    var searchActive : Bool = false
    var data = ["San Francisco","New York","San Jose","Chicago","Los Angeles","Austin","Seattle"]
    var filtered:[String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /* Setup delegates */
        SearchTableView.delegate = self
        SearchTableView.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = true;
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filtered = data.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
            let tmp: NSString = text as NSString
            let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive)
            return range.location != NSNotFound
        })
        if(filtered.count == 0){
            searchActive = false;
        } else {
            searchActive = true;
        }
        SearchTableView.reloadData()
    }



    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(searchActive) {
            return filtered.count
        }
        return data.count;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")! as UITableViewCell;
        if(searchActive){
            cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row];
        }

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen this code: it belongs to achrak, I copied from there only, it is not working

Comment: @RajatAttri it's working for me i update code in swift3

Comment: NSMutableArray = OrderArray, Filtered is same as urs! Still Not working

Comment: Can you show me the array how you declare and initalize also